# Android packet Sniffer/Filter

Tags: android, networking, filter, packets, sniffer

Is it possible to implement an Android packet Sniffer/Filter WITHOUT using

- root privileges
- VPN Service ?

Give the framework some class to intercept packets? I find only TrafficStats 
(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html#TrafficStats) but it report only quantitative informations (like numbers of packets or numbers of bytes). In other words, is there any Android framework component that allow to sniffer packets send and received by the phone?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> is there any Android framework component that allow to sniffer packets send and received by the phone?

Fortunately, no, for blindingly obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: But Android give a Service to monitoring the usage of the network. How do you think it's implemented? At kernel level?

Comment: @Alexander910: "At kernel level?" -- most likely, yes.

Comment: So the only way to implement a sniffer in Android (without root privileges) is to use a VPN Network ad hoc like a tunnel beetween the device and the network? thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Alexander910: Or, presumably, via root. But, yes, those are your two options.